# Select every element inside ElementA that is not inside ElementB where ElementB is inside ElementA

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

How do I write this idea in CSS:

Select every element inside ElementA that is not inside ElementB where ElementB is inside ElementA.

Here is an example:

```
<table id="ElementA">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Paragraph One</p>
        </td>
        <td class="ElementB">
            <p>Paragraph Two</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try to turn the text "Paragraph One" to "color: red" without changing the color of Paragraph Two.

I tried:

```
#ElementA *:not(.ElementB *) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

This is not homework; Twitter Bootstrap is messing with google maps by changing the max-width and line-height properties of the controls on the map. I want bootstrap to apply to the info window (which when open is inside the element) but not the zoom control or distance scale.

Edit 1:
the better example for how your solution will be used is probably this:

```
<div id="ElementA">
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ElementB">
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph Two</p>
            <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Goal: apply css properties to every element in ElementA except any element in ElementB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#ElementA td:not(.ElementB)  p{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Lsn5D/)

**New example. With divs and sort of different structure**

Now , for the new example you posted afterwards, you can use this other solution. Very similar

For

```
<div id="ElementA">
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ElementB">
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph Two</p>
            <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

use

```
 #ElementA >div:not(.ElementB)  {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
#ElementA >div:not(.ElementB) p {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
```

both will work!

corresponding fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/D35BC/)

**Remember**: The not selector will work work as expected with compound selectors inside its parenthesis

Comment: This did work for the example however my real application is more like:
'<div id="ElementA">
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ElementB">
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph Two</p>
            <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'
and the equivalent
'#ElementA div:not(.ElementB) * {}'
doesn't work in my code.

Comment: In answer to your comment under my answer, take a look at [your second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D35BC/3/) with a non-inherited property set (your original has just `color` set which is inherited). The `border` does not propagate to the `p` of paragraph one (it is only on the `div` surrounding it). The requirements of the question stated that the properties had to apply to "every element in ElementA" except those in "ElementB".

Comment: @ScottS Thank you, I appreciate your comment .

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can only be done if `.ElementB` is a known (set) depth from `#ElementA`. In your case here, the answer would be this:

```
#ElementA > :not(.ElementB),
#ElementA > :not(.ElementB) * {
    /* styles to apply */
}
```

**[See fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jWqNF/2/)**

If you intend `.ElementB` itself to also have the styles applied, then you have [some other issues with inherited css](http://jsfiddle.net/jWqNF/7/) (unless you don't mind that default behavior). You would have to reset properties that inherit by default if you don't want them to change:

```
#ElementA > *,
#ElementA > :not(.ElementB) * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: blue;
}

#ElementA > .ElementB * {
    color: black;
}
```

**[See fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jWqNF/8/)**

Comment: Both examples I developed in my answer works fine in my fiddles. I dont see where can be the trouble?

Comment: @Fico: Your answer relies on `.ElementB` being a child of `.ElementA` and not being nested at an arbitrary depth.

Comment: @BoltClock: My answer also relies on knowing the relation between the elements. Arbitrary depth is not stated as a requirement in the question. (However, because of an earlier question that did ask that, I made sure to note in this answer that the position of relation between `.ElementB` and `.ElementA` had to be known to make it work.)